# the present perfect+The future tense

Tags: grammar

I read the news and I saw this: "The government has said it will not accept blackmail." Should it nobe like: the government has said it would not accept blacmail.

Comment: No, because "will" expresses a more positive intention than "would" which may be tentative or perhaps conditional.

Comment: @BillJ: To me, using Present Perfect (or even Simple Present *the government **says** it won't be blackmailed*) conveys a greater sense of "immediacy". Which all feeds in to the general sense of a ***current*** pressing issue involving parties with *definite* (but conflicting) positions.

Comment: I guess it depends on if the government has or has not received blackmail demands.